# Unable to get Projekktor to play more than one YouTube video in my playlist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube

I'm trying to get Projekktor to run a playlist of YouTube videos.
I manage to get the first video to play but then it stops.
My code is shown below:

```
<div id="player_a" class="projekktor"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    projekktor('#player_a', {
        controls: true,
        volume: 0.5,
        autoplay: true,
        playlist : [
            {
                0:{src:'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5akYnlwubDo', type: 'video/youtube'},
                1:{src:'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O8RhZDGLEXM', type: 'video/youtube'},
                2:{src:'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wFfD15_HbBY', type: 'video/youtube'}
            }
        ]

    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your playlist array has the wrong format. Putting multiple sources into one item object is for providing multiple sources in different formats only. Try the following to set up a reel of (youtube) videos:

```
<div id="player_a" class="projekktor"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    projekktor('#player_a', {
        controls: true,
        volume: 0.5,
        autoplay: true,
        playlist : [
            {0:{src:'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5akYnlwubDo', type: 'video/youtube'}},
            {0:{src:'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O8RhZDGLEXM', type: 'video/youtube'}},
            {0:{src:'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wFfD15_HbBY', type: 'video/youtube'}}
        ]

    });
});
</script>
```