# Play YouTube video with custom web player

Tags: html, video, youtube, projekktor

I need to embed Youtube videos on the site... But without the YouTube logo...

I suppose I need to use a custom web player, like [projekktor](http://www.projekktor.com/)...

But in its [online example](http://www.projekktor.com/demos/javascript/) of adding youtube (to the playlist in their case) this feature does not work (the mp4 video plays normally, then Youtube video fails to play - invalid stream)...

Is the example or projekktor problem?
What are other ways to (freely) embed YouTube in a customized player (witout youtube logo) ?

Here is another [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245023/unable-to-get-projekktor-to-play-more-than-one-youtube-video-in-my-playlist), but I have the same "output" - invalid stream for YouTube links...

Comment: if you try and use the youTube examples in the sample you link to you'll notice it fails... I imagine since Projekktor was released youTube have made changes to acceptable ways of playing back their content - I've seen them getting more restrictive to preserve both their brand and the ability to control advertising

Answer (score 1):

i have created jquery plugin for custom youtube player based on tube player,,
glad if it as you expect

you can get it on github.
https://github.com/qutek/FunkTube